# Collision/Trigger with Particle System

Tags: unity, particles

I have a fire particle system in my game. I want to over the game when player collides/triggers with that particle system. As I've researched for this on google, I came to know that I can use World Particle Collision component for that. By sending Collision message on colliding, collision can be detected. I've put following snippet in player's script to detect particle collision.

```
void OnParticleCollision(GameObject TargetedParticle)
{
    Debug.Log ("Collided with particle");
}
```

Am I doing this in a right way? Because This code is not enable to detect collision. Help me please.

Comment: do you have "detect collision" enabled on the particle effect?

Answer (score 1):

The player object should have a rigidbody collider. Enable the 'box collider'.

The 'Send Collision Message' should also be enabled in the particle system dropdown(under the collision tab).